# DatePipe displaying hours incorrectly on mobile [Angular]

Tags: angular

Using datepipe on a date shows 3 hours ahead (+3) on mobile while it displays correct hour on mac. Example: Using | date : 'short' for the date 2018-04-02T06:00:00 shows 02.04.2018 06:00 on mac and 02.04.2018 09:00 on iphone (also in simulator). The problem is occur on formatting but why it is just happening only on mobile?

Comment: Could this be timezone-related ? You have a date, but your "phone" is in a timezone 3 hours ahead ?

Comment: No, it's not 3 hours ahead. And it's display hour correctly before formatting. @trichetriche

Comment: can you please confirm that both the mobile and mac have the same time and time zone since Timezone of the formatted text will be the local system timezone of the end-user's machine.

Comment: It shows 2018-04-02T06:00:00 datetime before formatting in both mac and iphone. @AravindS

Comment: I've solved this issue by using a custom datepipe. Check here for the solution: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-using.html